# Rails best practice for app with only one user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, activerecord

I am building a website for a client that wants to be able to make edits to things on their website.  As such I need a way to allow the client to login to the site to make their changes.

My initial thought was to make an authentication system that relies on a User table in the database that is capped at one and only one user.  It seems sort of overkill however to make a database table for just one result, so I was wondering if there were any other approaches or best practices that anyone could point to for building a site with just one user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply authenticate with a static password that is received from a file(encrypted), if you do not want a db model for that.

However, setting authentication with a gem like Devise is like 10 minutes of work. In order to be more secure(it can be a matter even in single user apps), you can set it up and be fine :)

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend you set up authentication. As SpyrosP said it does not take long when you use Devise.